# Where are servlet and JAX-RS dependencies coming from?

Tags: java, maven, servlets, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

If I include the following J2EE dependency in my application, I have access to servlet and JAX-RS classes and interfaces:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

But where are they coming from? On Maven Central I see that [`javax:javaee-api:7.0`](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cjavax%7Cjavaee-api%7C7.0%7Cjar) has as a dependency [`javax:javaee-web-api:7.0`](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cjavax%7Cjavaee-web-api%7C7.0%7Cjar), which in turn has as dependencies `javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0` and `javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.0`, so on the face of it, that's the answer.

But all those dependencies are marked as *`optional`*, which means that as transitive dependencies they wouldn't show up for my project unless I explicitly include them. But yet my program compiles simply with a dependency to `javax:javaee-api:7.0`. Why?

Here is my dependency tree; I don't see where they are coming in:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ temp-server ---
[INFO] com.example:test-server:war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.1:provided
[INFO] \- javax:javaee-api:jar:7.0:compile
[INFO]    \- com.sun.mail:javax.mail:jar:1.5.0:compile
[INFO]       \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
```

(This is all basic stuff; I don't know why I'm confused. I must be missing something obvious.)

Comment: Which class in particular are you talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `JAX-RS 2.0` is part of `Java EE 7`, the classes defining its API are directly included into the artifact `javax:javaee-api:7.0` so it is enough to compile your program as long as you use standard classes only.

Comment: So the JAX-RS classes, for example, are duplicated in `javax:javaee-api:7.0` and in `javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.0`? (And I guess they did this in case someone didn't have dependency management?)

Comment: They are only `optional` dependencies as you have already mentioned so I don't think so but anyway at then it should be defined as `provided` so it doesn't really matter. I guess `javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.0` is meant to be used by people doing pure JX-RS app or that doesn't want to have the full API to compile

Comment: By "duplicated" I mean that Java included the JAX-RS `.class` files in both `javax:javaee-api:7.0` and in `javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.0`, even though the former includes the latter as a dependency. That answers my question; I hadn't considered that the `.class` files would be in both JAR files, because one is the dependency of the other. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

Here, you need to understand what is meant by `<scope>provided</scope>`. The `javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0` and `javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.0` will be included with scope as `provided` when including the `javaee-api` dependency. What this means is that, **ONLY** while compiling your classes, these jar files will be used and **NOT** at runtime. Since the scope is `provided`, it expects that these 2 jars will be given by the runtime environment. To re-iterate, when any jar is included with scope as `provided`, it means this jar should be used for compilation, but for runtime, it expects to be provided by the runtime container.

Now to answer your question, if you consider any runtime environment container such as `JBOSS`, `WAS`, etc, they all come bundled with these jars. So at the time of compiling your classes, it will make use of the jars that come as transitive dependencies to `javaee-api`, but at run time it will make use of the jars that came bundled with the container instead. Hence you don't get any error.

Comment: I understand `<scope>provided</scope>`, but that is completely beside the question. This question was about `<optional>`. And it was about compile-time, not run-time, dependencies. Please reread the question. Your answer was very good---for a different question.

Comment: @Garett, are you using any classes from those optional jars in your application ?

Comment: This was merely a question to find out how my compiler was seeing files in `javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.0` that were referenced transitively (but using `optional`) two layers down from `javax:javaee-api:7.0`. The answer (given by Nicolas Filotto) is that the relevant classes are _also_ included in `javax:javaee-api:7.0`, so the they were _not_ being included transitively. I am so used to good modularization that I failed to consider that the JAX-RS classes might be included in _both_ jars, even though one referenced the other. End of story. Question answered.